# why "describe" command not working in netbeans for oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

I am using net-beans 8.1 and oracle 12c as database in windows 8. When i am trying the command "describe" in net-beans, it is showing the error given given below..

```
describe T; 

Error code 900, SQL state 42000: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Line 1, column 1
Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

But the same command is working in command line.

```
SQL> describe T;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

Please any one clear it to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`describe` is a `SQL*Plus` command not a SQL or PL/SQL command.  It can only be used in `SQL*Plus` or some other client tool that happens to implement a subset of the available `SQL*Plus` commands.  I know that SQL Developer implements `describe`.  I'm sure other tools do as well.

You can get the same information by querying `all_tab_columns`

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision
  from all_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'T'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql script editor in netbeans it wont work for oracle its sql based command.

Hope this helps